# Disable aspxerrorpath parameter in ASP.Net URL

Tags: asp.net, web-config, custom-error-pages, custom-errors

I've added the following to my web.config to redirect a user to a custom error page instead of the default

> Server Error in '/' Application.

error message.

The user get's redirected to `error.html?aspxerrorpath=/paymentservices.svc`

Is there a way to remove the `?aspxerrorpath=/paymentservices.svc` part?

**web.config:**

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPages/error.html"
  mode="On" xdt:Transform="Replace">
    <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/ErrorPages/error.html"/>
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/ErrorPages/error.html"/>
    </customErrors>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 6):

A cheap way is to just add your own query string to end of the error - it should overwrite the "default" one.  Even an empty string should work.

`<error statusCode="500" redirect="~/ErrorPages/error.html?"/>`

Or you could add your own error handling to Application_Error in Global.ascx

Answer (score 3):

You could try rewriting the response

```
<customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" >
    ....
</customErrors>
```